# Can't print String from function (in react tictactoe tutorial)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to implement the first improvement after completing the tictactoe react tutorial: `Display the location for each move in the format (col, row) in the move history list.`

But my `(col,row)`'s, despite being correctly calculated, aren't being printed in the buttons. My buttons get texts like `Go to move #1 (undefined)`. The `(col,row)` value should be printed instead of that undefined.

Why is it happening?

Here's my code:

```
 render() {
  const history = this.state.history;
  const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
  const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);

  const moves = history.map((step,move) => {
    const desc = move ? 'Go to move # ' + move + ' ('+getRowCol(history, move)+ ')': 'Go to game start';
    return (
      <li key={move}><button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button></li>
    )
  });

 (...)

 function getRowCol(history, move){
  let array1 = history[move].squares;
  let array2 = history[move-1].squares;
  array1.forEach((item,index) => {
   if(item !== array2[index]){
    return nomearIndice(index);
   } 
  });
 }
 function nomearIndice(indice){
  let retorno = indice < 3 ? '1,' : indice < 6 ? '2,' : '3,';
  if([0,3,6].includes(indice)){
   return retorno + '1';
  } if([1,4,7].includes(indice)){ 
   return retorno + '2';
  } if([2,5,8].includes(indice)){
   return retorno + '3';
  }
 }
```

So I run `history.map` in line 6 of the code sample, this method calls `getRowCol` function and, as far as I can tell by putting a million `console.log`s in the code, it works fine. I guess JS isn't waiting until my `getRowCol` function returns and is producing this undesired result. Is it the problem? If so, how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are returning anything from getRowCol
Try

```
function getRowCol(history, move) {
  let array1 = history[move].squares;
  let array2 = history[move - 1].squares;
  return array1.map((item, index) => {
    if (item !== array2[index]) {
      return nomearIndice(index);
    }
  });
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/spliffmon/pen/MWwKGKv?editors=0010) is a demo using map and returning the result. However, I'm not sure what output you are expecting.

Can you explain what result you want from getRowCol (eg an example) and I can try to help.

I've updated the demo to reflect the behaviour you are after using

```js
function getRowCol(history, move) {
  let array1 = history[move].squares;
  let array2 = history[move - 1].squares;

  return array1.reduce((accumulator, item, index) => {
    return (item === array2[index]) ? accumulator : nomearIndice(index);
  }, '');
}
```

Comment: Hi! I tried adding `return` to the forEach, but nothing changed. =/

Comment: What are you hoping to get? An array or row cols? If you are. You need to use map instead of forEach

Comment: I expect that the first occurence of `item !== array2[index]` in the forEach will make the getRowCol function return a String, generated by `nomearIndice()`.

Comment: forEach does not return anything.[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is the MDN docs.

Comment: That's it. I was thinking it would work like a regular for loop. Thank you!